# Can faulty O2 sensor cause omission check engine light?

Tags: subaru, o2-sensor, catalytic-converter, warning-light

I have had a check engine on a 2001 Subaru Legacy for some time now. Went to mechanic to fix few other things and he told me the oxygen sensor and catalytic converter needs to be replaced. The catalytic converter was installed by the small dealership I got the car from around January this year. Assuming the emissions fault code is not due to the catalytic converter, can the O2 sensor trigger such a code?

**UPDATE**
I bought a BAFX Bluetooth OBD2 Scan Tool and tried it today. Although the check-engine light went away after the serpantine belt was [replaced](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/13032/vibrating-sound-and-shaking-when-turning-the-wheel-after-changing-timing-belt/13034?noredirect=1#comment16869_13034), I checked with the tool and got **Fault Code P0420**. And the O2 sensor bank 1 sensor 2 (picture attached) was showing 0.1V-0.3V. I cleared the codes and will see if it comes back in few days. Could the bad belt/wheelie trigger this error?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Well, the mechanic that did my timing belt made notice that the O2 sensor needs to be replaces, and the catalytics converter as well. The cat was done withing the last year. So I am not sure what triggered the error code. I will replace the O2 sensor, reset the code, and will update here later on.

Comment: Note that there's two cats and two sensors; you should double-check which are problematic.

Comment: How can I check that? I asked the mechanic about which cat, he said that this one in my car is a full single piece.

Comment: The diagnostic code will indicate which it is. You should be able to get it read for free at your local parts store. There should be, as far as I know, three sections to your exhaust: first section includes the front cat and sensor, second section the rear pair, and the last goes back to the muffler. Unless somebody did something weird: my Forester had a piece of pipe welded across what should have been the joint for the two rear sections when I got it, so when I needed to do the rear cat, I had to do the end pipe as well.

Comment: I need to see the whole unit. A small dealership replaced it before my friend got it, and in turn I got it from him. They claimed to have replaced one of the cats. So I would want to believe that nothing is welded. How much was yours? The mechanic quoted me for close to $700 to do the cat, and $165 for the O2 sensor, without labor costs.

Comment: That's definitely the right ballpark. Catalytic converters are expensive. I'd think you could get a cheaper sensor, but I'm not positive.

Comment: Also, if the cat failed within a year, something else is  with your engine. I've heard people implicating failing head gaskets for that.

Comment: I drove the car all day yesterday (80+ miles) and today the check-engine light was gone without me reseting it. Could the emissions error code was due to a faulty timing belt?

Comment: Other things besides emission problems will turn on the CEL; without knowing what the code actually was, it's impossible to say why it turned on or off. (Also, it wasn't your timing belt that was replaced, as Paulster noted on your other question.)

Comment: I updated the question with results from the OBD scanner. The error code was P0420 - Catalytic System Efficiency Below Threshold (Bank 1) - What is the threshold?

Answer (score 3):

Short answer, yes - a faulty O2 can make the Check Engine Light / MIL to go on.

Do you know what the code is?

Comment: P0420. See update on the question.

Comment: Yes, this code can trigger the check engine light